# tortoise svn cant open file the handle is invalid

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

When i am trying to use tortoisesvn on windows to do an update, i keep getting the following errors for a specific folder.

Can someone please let me know how to fix this problem and how it occurred?

```
Can't open file 
'C:\Users\myname\Documents\projects\cpe\lab\.svn\tmp\text-base\con.svn-base': 
The handle is invalid.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> andyl from [svnforum.com](http://www.svnforum.org/)
>
> con is an illegal filename in Windows. Rename the file via Repo
>   Browser to conform to MS's rules.
>
> [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr...%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This fixed the issue.