# TortoiseSVN checkout and update failure due to "Can't write to stream: The handle is invalid."

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I am trying to checkout a project using TortoiseSVN, but I keep getting the error

"Can't write to stream: The handle is invalid."

I am connecting to the repo using ssh+svn, which I configured to use a .ppk file, and putty/pageant. I am able to use the TortoiseSVN repo-browser to browse the files in the repo without a problem, so I am confident that the ssh+svn configuration is correct.

I can use the repo-browser to open a copy of any file in the repo.

I can use the repo-browser to view the log for a file/directory in the repo.

I have tried checking out to different directories and different drives, but I always get the same error.

I have been unable to find any other mention of this specific error in any of my google searches; does anyone have any idea what's going on or how to debug and fix it?

== EDIT ==

I got the error with TortoiseSVN 1.14.5, Build 29465 - 64 Bit , 2022/09/24 08:31:31
(I got the same error with an earlier version of TortoiseSVN as well, but did not note the version)

I was able to attempt the same checkout using the svn.exe that comes with the tortoise install on the commandline, and received the same error, though this time with an error code:

```
svn: E720006: Can't write to stream: The handle is invalid.
```

Comment: Seems like another user had the same problem (no answers there, so no duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740471/svn-checkout-error-e720006-error-running-context and a possibly related issue where a blacklisted filename was the cause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438586/tortoise-svn-cant-open-file-the-handle-is-invalid

Comment: @Friedrich Thank you for the response! I did not notice the first post (probably because I did not find that error code until later in my investigation).

I am reasonably sure that it's not a blacklist issue; I have had this project checked out on this same computer via tortoisesvn previously, I just had my data drive replaced, so I am checking it out on this drive for the first time.

My company does use Sophos to protect our PCs, but I did temporarily disable that and try, as well as in the "dev folder" that our IT set up to be a whitelisted location that Sophos sort of ignores.